# Change of Address

Tags: wordpress, google-search-console

I changed my website domain and used a change of address in the new google search console. But now Google is taking both the domain (new and old) as a different site and I am having Duplicate content issues. I have done 301 redirections. They are same site but only change in the domain name. I don't have to have any effects on SEO rankings or have a Google penalty. How to solve this issue?

Comment: Please refer to the following tutorial: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/9370220 It has all the details which may help you to fix the issue.

Comment: I have done all the things as per google have stated but still having these issues. And there's aren't any tutorials on new google search console... all the blog and tutorials are on the old version of google console...I just worried that I might have done it wrong.